# How do I add new lines to my title?

Tags: titles

I am trying to make a title for my pdf:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Poisson Image Editting}
\date{\today}
\author{David Faux}

\maketitle

\section{Abstract}
derp derp derp.

\end{document}
```

I also want to include in my title section (preferably right under the date) the lines

```
"Math 54"
"Professor Farber"
```

How do I do that? I've tried listing the content right under the title to no avail. `\subtitle` also doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Unrelated: there is an `abstract` environment for writing the abstract, in case you were not aware of it. You use it as `\begin{abstract} <... abstract material ...> \end{abstract}`.

Answer (score 4):

`\title{<stuff>}` merely stores `<stuff>` in the macro `\@title`, which is then used/typeset when you call `\maketitle`. So, the easiest way to stack content is to use

```
\title{Poisson Image Editing \\ Math 54 \\ Professor Farber}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`\title{xxx}`,`\date{yyy}` and `\author{zzz}` just show xxx, yyy, zzz in your title page. It is designed to put title, date and author information there. However, you can put any text with any style you want there.

```
\title{Poisson Image Editing \\{\Large Math 54} \\{\Large Professor Farber}}
```

Other than the subtitles, here are some more informations I usually put into the title myself.

conference/city of the report

```
\date{xx{\it th} Annual Meeting of XXXX \\ 12/10/2013 San Francisco, CA}
```

affiliation, contact information

```
\author{David Faux \\ {\tt xxx@yyy.com}}
```

So all three lines above will generate this title page

[image]

This only gives you an example of what basic freedoms you have to customize the title. You can surely further explore more options yourself.